# tapping power from a 3 way switch to an adjacent 2 way switch

Tags: switch

I have a ceiling fixture that is controlled through 2 3-way switches (power comes from the fixture not to one of the switches).  in the same room, there is a set of wall light fixtures that are tied to one switch installed next to one of the 3-way switches (the power was coming to the single pole switch until we finished the basement and the contractor damaged the wiring without noticing).  can I power the single pole tapping power from the 3-way switch?  will the wall fixtures be tied to the ceiling fixture?  I did a trial but the operation was reversed (i.e. I can only turn the wall lights on if the ceiling lights were off).

Comment: Can you provide a diagram (or photos) of the current wiring layout? There is more than one way to wire up a set of 3-way switches and maybe there's a way to do what you want here which isn't apparent yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the hot wire is coming first to the **other** 3-way switch. From there, power comes on one of the two travelers to the 3-way you're working with. You've probably connected your new switch to one of the travelers. I'd bet if you switch the other 3-way, the light will come on and off together.

Without the hot coming to this 3-way, you cannot have independent operation of the new switch.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response.  I'll try it this weekend and see.